# Metodo en el v-switch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Hola estoy comenzando en este mundo y tengo un duda, como hago para pasarle el valor del v-switch a un metodo si este posee un arreglo asociado, este es mi codigo para ver si lo entienden:

este es mi switch, posee un valor false por defecto, quiero que al activar el switch, llame a un evento y le envie el valor que esta tomando:

```
            <v-switch
              v-model="anyPromo.activar"
              label="Activar promción"
              @change="changeState(value)"
            ></v-switch>
```

luego en el export esta asi:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      anyPromo: {
        activar: false
}
```

y el metodo esta de esta fomra:

```
methods:{
    changeState(valor) {
        console.log("Switch "+valor);
     
    }
}
```

pero no me funciona, disculpen los errores apenas comienzo en este mundo, de antemano gracias...

Comment: anyPromo.activar cambia el valor solo dependiendo de lo que tenga el switch... no tenes que hacer nada al respecto.. esa es la filosofia de vue... o no entendiste como funciona vue, o yo no entiendo que tratas de hacer...

Comment: como se el valor nuevo que esta tomando el switch????

Comment: esta dentro de la variable conectada al switch por el v-model... no lo ves cambiar en el depurador?

Comment: No, por eso mi duda, me trae undefined...

Comment: no tenes algun error en la consola?

Comment: y quiero suponer que ese data tiene todas las llaves de cierre que faltan no?

Comment: si, sintaxis esta bien, solo quiero que al hacer click al switch, llame un evento y me traiga el NUEVO valor...

Comment: entonces no te estoy entendiendo.. el valor esta en la variable que vos conectaste por el v-model... si la ves como undefined, es porque algo esta mal definido y tendrias un error en la consola... tal vez alguien te entienda mejor...

Comment: gracias igual por tu tiempo, muy amable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas dar `value` a `changeState` como: `(value) => changeState(value)`.
También debes recordar envolver tu aplicación en `<v-app>` para que el `switch` funcione.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-switch
      :v-model="anyPromo.activar"
      :input-value="anyPromo.activar"
      label="Activar promción"
      @change="(value) => changeState(value)"
    ></v-switch>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      anyPromo: {
        activar: true,
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeState(valor) {
      this.anyPromo.activar = valor;
      console.log("Switch " + valor);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Aquí tienes una [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-booth-psywc?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) que funciona.

Comment: gracias...muy amable

Comment: esa es mejor muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hola gracias aqui la respuesta por si le sirve a alguien...

en el v-switch agregar este codigo:

```
   @change="toggleActive(anyPromo)"
```

y aqui el metodo:

```
   toggleActive(value){
   
      console.log('valor nuevo',value.activar)
    },
```